# R: Evaluating a script in an environment

Tags: r, scope, eval, r-environment

I would like to load a library function within a script evaluated in a specified environment.

Example:

```
## foo.R
## -----

## blah blah 

library(extrafont)
loadfonts()
```

Assuming for convenience the evaluation  environment is the base environment:

```
sys.source("foo.R")
## Registering fonts with R
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "loadfonts"
```

Replacing `loadfonts()` with `extrafont:::loadfonts()` works better, but still gives:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'pdfFonts' of mode 'function' was not found
```

because `loadfonts()` requires `pdfFonts()` defined in `grDevices`.

Comment: `e<- new.env() source("foo.R", local=e)` will evaluate your foo.R in that environment only. So you could also require the grDevices library in foo.R

Comment: @waterling: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is both a not totally satisfactory answer and a long comment to  @waterling.

The proposed solution is:

```
e<- new.env() 
source("foo.R", local=e)
```

i.e.

```
source("foo.R", local=new.env())
```

which is substantially equivalent to:

```
sys.source("foo.R", envir=new.env())
```

It works for much the same reason why:

```
sys.source("foo.R", envir=as.environment("package:grDevices"))
```

As reported in the error (see question), the function not found, `pdfFonts()`  is part of the package `grDevices`   The `sys.source` above executes  the script in the `package:grDevices` environment, hence the function is found. Instead by default `sys.source(..., envir=baseenv())` and the base environment comes before `grDevices`, therefore `pdfFonts()`  is not found.

A first problem is that I do  not know in advance which functions will happen to  be in my script. 
In this case setting  `envir=new.env()` is a more general approach.  By default
`new.env(parent=parent.frame())`, 
therefore it  has the  same parent of  `sys.source()`, which  is the global environment. So everything visible in the global environment is visible in the script with `sys.source(..., envir=new.env())`, that is every object created by the user and by the  user  loaded packages.

The problem here is that we are not insulating the script any more, which  makes  it less  reproducible and stable. In fact, it depends on what is in R memory in the very moment we call `sys.source`. 
To make the things more practical, it means   `foo.R` might work just because we *usually* call it after `bar.R`.

A second problem is that this not an actual solution. 
The question concerns *how to run a script `foo.R` in an environment `e` and still access, when needed, to functions  not belonging to `e`.*  Taking an  `e` that (directly or through its parents) has access to these functions is actually a  workaround, not a solution.

If this type of workaround  is the only possible way to go, IMHO, the best is to make it dependent only on standard R packages.
At start, R shows:

```
search()
## [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
## [4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
## [7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

that is eight official packages/environments.
New packages/environments, unless explicitly changing the default, go into the second slot and all those  after the first one  shift one position.

```
myEnv=new.env()
attach(myEnv)
search()
##  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "myEnv"             "package:stats"    
##  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
##  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
## [10] "package:base"
```

So we can take the last eight in the search path, which means taking the first of these eight inheriting the others. We need:

```
pos.to.env(length(search()) - 7)
## <environment: package:stats>
## attr(,"name")
## [1] "package:stats"
## attr(,"path")
## [1] "path/to//R/R-x.x.x/library/stats"
```

Therefore:

```
sys.source("foo.R", envir=new.env(parent=pos.to.env(length(search()) - 7)))
```

or one can take a standard R reference package, say `stats`, and its parents.

Therefore:

```
sys.source("foo.R", envir=new.env(parent=as.environment("package:stats")))
```

### UPDATE

I found the

## SOLUTION

As for the script:

```
#foo.R
#-----
library(extrafont)
f=function() loadfonts()
environment(f) = as.environment("package:extrafont")
f()
```

To execute in a new environment:

```
sys.source("foo.R", envir=new.env(parent=baseenv()))
```

`f()` now has access to all objects in   the package `extrafont` and those loaded before  it.

In  `sys.source()` creating a `new.env()` with whatever parent is necessary to make `environment()` assignment work.